# Adding a link to an external project, and its dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, clickonce

I am trying to publish two different executables using ClickOnce - where one is executing the other, I have looked around and found a suggestion to add a link to the executable in the project files and setting it to content and copy always  - now, this works great except, the dependencies used by that executable aren't copied -

Is there a simpler way to get it to copy the dependencies without creating links to every dll or config file?

Comment: I am reading through, and it seems like an awful explanation - but I have no idea how to explain it better and if you have tried to do the same thing you should be able to understand what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to add a reference to the other executable, instead of including it as a link.